# Is this Geometry Feasible?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles

I came across a problem from SASMO(Singapore) Olympiad sample paper. Here is the problem:

[image]

I gave this problem to my students and made them solve. Happily, they have solved and told the answer as $22$cm.

Now comes the Tragedy!!!

I asked them to find the length of $OR$. So let us find now.

It is evident that $$RP=OQ=7$$

Let $OR=x \Rightarrow OP=10-x$. Now by Pythagoras theorem, we get
$$x^2+(10-x)^2=49 \Rightarrow 2x^2-20x+51=0$$ which has complex roots. Boom!

EDIT:
Well then what is the moral?
We need to find Maximum perimeter of rectangle that can be inscribed in a quarter circle of radius $7$cm.

Let the Perimeter be $2\lambda$

We have $$OR^2+RP^2=49 \Rightarrow x^2+(\lambda-x)^2=49 \Rightarrow \lambda=x+\sqrt{49-x^2}$$

Take $x=7\sin t$, we get $$\lambda=7(\sin t+\cos t) \leq 7\sqrt{2} \Rightarrow 2\lambda \leq 14\sqrt{2}<20$$

Comment: Maybe I miss something but why $OR = x \Rightarrow OP = 10-x$?

Comment: @Qise length+breadth=$10$, since perimeter is $20$

Comment: The hypothesis of the exercise was impossible, that's all.

Comment: @AnneBauval this is what I suspected also. Can you point out what is not working exactly?

Comment: Exactly what you wrote. The perimeter of the rectangle is too large to fit inside the quarter of disc.

Comment: The biggest (by perimeter) rectangle that can be inscribed in the way you depict is the square, and the perimeter of that is $<20$.  How were they meant to get $22$?

Comment: @lulu Assume the geometry is possible. The perimeter of the quarter circle is $11+7+7=25$ (with $\pi=22/7$). The diagonal of the rectangle $(7)$ is $3$ less than its half-perimeter $(10)$ giving the answer as $22$.

Comment: @nickgard  Ah, thanks.  I couldn't get past the missing $\pi$.

Comment: There's a famous (if somewhat insulting) "impossible figure" problem, along these lines, which your students might find entertaining, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594740/v-i-arnold-says-russian-students-cant-solve-this-problem-but-american-student).  Good lesson in the dangers of mechanically applying formulas, if nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, boom.

The objective may not actually have been to get numbers. It may have been to test critical thinking by checking that the conditions are in fact realistic. In fact a rectangle inscribed in a quarter-circle as shown must have a perimeter less than or equal to that of a square in that position, which we can easily work out as $4(r/\sqrt2)=r\sqrt8$. But your perimeter/radius ratio is $\sqrt{400/49}$ and $8$ is only $392/49$.

See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4119675/248217), and maybe do [a little light reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_New_Clothes).

[image] [Illustration source](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Emperor_Clothes_01.jpg#mw-jump-to-license)

Answer (score 1):

Take the sides of the rectangle to be $a,b.$

Then, $98=2a^2+2b^2\ge (a+b)^2=100.$ Impossible.

Comment: This is nothing more that the OP: take the sides of the rectangle to be $x,10-x.$ Then, $49=x^2+(10-x)^2\ge50.$ Impossible.

Comment: Yes using $QM \geq AM$, Maxiumum perimeter of rectangle is $19.7989..$cm